# app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I get this error when trying to build AOT:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'AngularSplitModule in /tmp/build_21988d7923d361e412b5069abeec38ff/node_modules/angular-split/dist/angularSplit.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /tmp/build_21988d7923d361e412b5069abeec38ff/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

I've tried some things I've read on the webs but I cant seem to get it to work. :S

This is my app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './routing/routing.module';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './task/task.component';
import { DoodleComponent } from './task/doodle/doodle.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { ManagerComponent } from './task/manager/manager.component';
import { QuestionComponent } from './task/question/question.component';

import { FieldsService } from './task/services/fields.service';
import { QuestionService } from './task/services/question.service';
import { AnswerService } from './task/services/answer.service';

import { SidebarModule } from 'ng-sidebar';
import { AngularSplitModule } from 'angular-split';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    DoodleComponent,
    MainComponent,
    ManagerComponent,
    QuestionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularSplitModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SidebarModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [FieldsService, QuestionService, AnswerService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've tried to downgrade the angular-split to a lower version but I get other errors then. So, what is the problem and how can I fix it? :)

Best regards

-------------------------edit-----------------------------

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.4",
    "npm": "5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "watch-build": "ng build --watch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-split": "0.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some version numbers you are using? Especially angular, angular cli, typescript and the angular-split version may be helpful. Also, is [this](https://github.com/bertrandg/angular-split) the AngularSplit that you are using?

Comment: done, in edit..

Comment: First of all I'd try to update angular-split to the _fixed_ version 0.2.2, so no higher for now cause the higher versions may only be compatible to angular 5. Is there a way that you can upgrade angular to version 5 or is that currently not possible?

Comment: I've tried 0.2.2 but it crashes in the same way. I will try to upgrade it later this evening to 5

Comment: The author of the package also emphasizes to completely uninstall and then install the package again, so `npm uninstall angular-split` followed by the install command.